# return value and passing arguments to isr

Tags: linux, embedded

ISR cannot return any value, also we cannot pass any argument to it.
But in Linux we use IRQ_NONE / IRQ_HANDLED because devices share IRQ line. So what is the main interrupt handler which donot return any value, also don't receive any argument and how it calls IRQ handlers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value of interrupt handlers in linux kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732570/return-value-of-interrupt-handlers-in-linux-kernel)

Comment: A true ISR as a whole can't return a value or have arguments.  But a helper routine which implements *part* of an ISR is just a function, which could have either or both if the API by which it interacts with the overall ISR provides for it.